# Cannot dismiss flag on a question that was migrated and merged

Tags: bug, status-completed, flags, migration, moderator-tools

There was a flag raised on Code Review about a question migrated from Stack Overflow.  A moderator marked it as a duplicate of an existing Code Review question and merged it.

However, the flag just *sticks*, no matter how many times we try to dismiss it as "helpful", or who tries to dismiss it.

<sub><sub>(...and it's wrecking our average flag-handling time!)</sub></sub>

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After this occurred again, I've fixed the question merge code to properly move comment flags on those comments that are also moved.

The way our Flags table is constructed, we have a foreign key to the question a flag is a child of, regardless of where that flag appears on the question, e.g. an answer flag, a comment flag on a comment on an answer, etc.  While this aides querying, it has to be kept in sync when those children move (this happens so rarely, thankfully).

Now I have to go write a test to ensure answer flags are also handled during merge :P

Comment: Wait, you wrote the fix *before* writing a test for it? How will you trust a green test that's never failed? ;-)

Comment: I wrote the test for comment flags before the fix (which failed).  After looking at the merge code, the answer flag test will also be failing :(

Comment: So much failure on a Friday.  So sad!